# How to make `syn-match` rule match only at specific postition?

Tags: vim, syntax, match, syntax-highlighting

I am working on some Vim syntax rules for a log file format.
I need a `syn match` to match only **after** a specific other `syn match`

For example:

- My data:

```
2021-08-24|  32|  ERR| 032| some_string with nasty s|ymbols §$Q§'äö| 932 ;,,
```

- My `syntax_def.vim`:

```
syn match traceLine '^\p*$' contains=timestamp,pid,name,line,string

syn match timestamp '\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d' contained nextgroup=pid
syn match pid       '\(|\s*\d\+\)\@>'    contained nextgroup=name
syn match name      '|\a\+\s*'           contained nextgroup=line
syn match line      '|\s*\d+'            contained nextgroup=string
syn match string    '|\p+'               contained
```

My problem is that the rule `pid` matches multiple times in this line.
I want it only to match once **after** `timestamp` and then not again.
Same applies to `line`. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

`nextgroup=` is basically just a hint to try given groups before anything else.

To get the desired result you have two option: **wrapper match** or **matching with specific column**.

#### Wrapper

We create a match applying to both `timestamp` and `pid`, make it transparent and shuffle arguments of `contains=`:

```
syn match traceLine '^\p*$' contains=timestamp_n_pid,name,line,string
syn match timestamp_n_pid '\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d|\s*\d\+' contained contains=timestamp,pid transparent
```

#### Matching with specific column

<sup>*(This method assumes `date` starts in first column)*</sup>

Since `date` has always format `XXXX-XX-XX`, i.e. it's 10 characters wide, we know that `pid` starts at 11th column. Then we can specify that in our RegEx by adding `\%11c` at the beginning:

```
syn match pid '\%11c\(|\s*\d\+\)\@>' contained nextgroup=name
```